# Assigning values to volatile array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, volatile

I have a volatile array of type `MyType` mapped to a shared memory, created with CreateFileMapping etc:

```
volatile MyType *arr;
```

How do I assign a value to an index of the array? E.g:

```
MyType a;
arr[n] = a;
```

I get the compile error:

> error C2678: binary '=' : no operator defined which takes a left-hand operand of type 'volatile MyType' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

I would like to be able to both be able to assign `MyType` to volatile and non-volatile arrays.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Side note: `volatile` is for [memory mapped I/O, long jump and certain variables in signal handlers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volatile_variable#In_C_and_C.2B.2B). Chances are you are not using any of those. Are you sure you have understood `volatile` and really need to use it?

Comment: @Shahbaz "I have a volatile array of type MyType mapped *to a shared memory*" Sounds like a good use to me.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes, not really. For example, in the case of memory mapped I/O, if you have `x = 10; x = 11;`, you need `x` to be written twice. Do you need such a thing with shared memory? Absolutely not. I have written a lot of code using shared memory, and I know the volatile is useless except very VERY special cases. What you should care about with shared memory is [memory barriers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_barrier), which exist in all `sleep` and sync lock functions. So unless you are busy waiting on a shared memory variable, the sleep inside the loop does what you intend...

Comment: ... which is make sure the loop variable is reread. You can also read more [here](http://kernel.org/doc/Documentation/volatile-considered-harmful.txt), to see an example of the very special case I mentioned. You could also read [here](http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2007/11/30/volatile-almost-useless-for-multi-threaded-programming/), if you are more interested, and [here(PDF)](http://www.cs.utah.edu/~regehr/papers/emsoft08-preprint.pdf) to see how easy it is for compilers to miscompile `volatile`.

Comment: @Shahbaz oh, that does make sense. Thanks. And thanks for links.

Comment: For future reference, even when you think you want busy waiting (which should be something rare), it is still better to do something like `while (var) sleep(0);`, which again invokes the memory barrier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did not mark your assignment operator as `volatile`. Volatile correctness is identical to const correctness- you have a `volatile` object but no volatile operator, so the call is ill formed.

Comment: The point is that I can not have a volatile MyType all through my application. Isn't there somekind of typecasting?

Comment: The assignment operator can be overloaded, just like you can overload on `const`.

Comment: Could you please give me an example I can't make it work:
MyType& operator=(const MyType t) volatile {THEN WHAT???}

Comment: I was considering giving you an example, but caps and multiple question marks? I'll skip.

Comment: Well, it appears somewhat normal to skip for that; but some other quiet people reading Stackoverflow may also like an answer ;-)